# Django Rest Framework Send verification email

Tags: python, django, rest, email, django-rest-framework

Is there any way to send a verification email. when an user registers through drf (Django Rest framework). I have this code in my `User` model:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from config import settings

def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, **kwargs):        
    send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email], fail_silently=False, **kwargs)
```

and in my `settings.py`:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '`132312123'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'mimic@gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

But email not being sent, also I want to verification email service, so user will be activated when they click on the link. How to accomplish these?

Answer (score 7):

If you look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/email/):

> Console backend
>
> Instead of sending out real emails the console backend just writes the
>   emails that would be sent to the standard output. By default, the
>   console backend writes to stdout. You can use a different stream-like
>   object by providing the stream keyword argument when constructing the
>   connection.

Also:

> This backend is not intended for use in production – it is provided as
>   a convenience that can be used during development.

Try this one instead:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

Comment: Good answer! I also suggest looking at email backends that send asynchronously, so that your users don't have to wait for the email to be actually sent (which is a slow process). I have been using https://github.com/pinax/django-mailer flawlessly. It uses database and it's dead simple to setup.